# I can't INSERT INTO after I send data from a js page

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

This is the code where I start.

```
 $('form').on('submit', function(e){
        $.post('sql.php', $(this).serialize());
        $.post('small.php', function(response){
            document.write(response);
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

I insert the data in sql.php:

```
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "usbw", "stage");
    $sql="INSERT INTO info (name, lastname, number) VALUES ('$_POST['name']', '$_POST['lastname']' , '$_POST['number']')";
   if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
   {
       die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
   }
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I don't know what I did wrong but this page doesn't want to insert the data in mysql

I noticed and corrected the missing "," and adjusted the $_POST values but the problem remains. I checked the console log, but it didn't say anything.

Comment: You might be getting error in your console log. In browser, press F12 key and go to console tab, you might see the error there.

Comment: _but this page doesn't want to insert the data_ whoa, never knew pages have a life on their own. So are you getting any errors?

Comment: you forgot to add a `,` after `$_POST[lastname]`

Comment: first of all you missed a comma in your query

Comment: The possible issues might be missing comma in your query,the post variables have different names,the db connection values are wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give the `$_POST` values in the query as `$_POST['keyname']` and not `'$_POST[keyname]'`. Or you can assign the `$_POST['keyname']` into another variable and substitute that variable in the query.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO info (name, lastname, number) VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."', '".$_POST['lastname']."', '".$_POST['number']."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented your code and it works well, there was an syntax error

```
<?php
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "usbw", "stage");
        $sql="INSERT INTO info (name, lastname, number) VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."', '".$_POST['lastname']."', '".$_POST['number']."')";
       if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
       {
           die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
       }
        mysqli_close($con);
?>
```